# Windows Forms: Why does output to textbox of long running algorithm stop after a while?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

I wrote a .NET application with a Windows Forms GUI. The application starts a long running algorithm in the main GUI thread (no second thread is created).

The algorithm logs progress information using System::Console. 
The System.Console is redirected to a TextBox using System.Console.SetOut().

For the first 10-30 seconds everything works fine and everything is logged to the TextBox. However, after a while the TextBox freezes and does not show any further logs - the missing logs a printed all at once after the algorithm has stopped.

The question is: why is this working for some time and then stops? In my understanding it should either work or work not.

P.S.: I understand that this kind of problem is best solved using second worker thread of the algorithm and some delegates to print out the log. But it is experimental code and I am just curious why it works for some time and then stops.

Comment: While I don't think that's the cause, can you say something about how much text is output? If it happens to be a "round" number (such a 4 KiB, 64 KiB, etc.) that may indicate some kind of buffering going on somewhere. This is really only a blind guess, though.

Comment: I do not think it is a round number. I seems more likely to happen if the window looses focus... or if is just move the mouse over another window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Application.DoEvents in the long-running process

Comment: I solved it doing a dirty hack (which is acceptable for our experimental tool): Adding a call to Application.DoEvents() into the hook for the System.Console redirect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you "eat" all CPU cycles, and do not permit Windows to update the UI.
   Working multithreaded or placinc calls to `Application.DoEvents` will give Windows permission to process the message queue, and update the UI.
2. Because you have reached the limit of text a textbox can contain (but you would get an exception if this is the case).

Comment: Maybe this is the solution. But why does it work for some time and then stops working? My guess is the following: the TextBox is called regularly (from Systen::Console redirect), so the TextBox itself is able to repaint itself. If for some reason however the whole window needs a repaint (if it e.g. lost focus) the TextBox is not able to repaint itself, since it's waiting for some action from the event loop (e.g. a whole window repaint).